# How do I get the active parameter value from React Router in my sidebar or nav to create a link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I may be approaching this incorrectly, but I'm following along with [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar) from the React Router docs.  In my case, one of the links from the Sidebar needs to have a nested parameter in it (eg `/bubblegum/:brand/nutrition`) so that my Sidebar looks more like this:

```
<ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
  <li>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</Link>
  </li>
{brand &&
<>
  <li>Selected Gum: {brand}</li>
  <li>
     <Link to="/bubblegum/{brand}/nutrition">Nutritional Information</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
     <Link to="/bubblegum/{brand}/history">History</Link>
  </li>
</>
}
  <li>
    <Link to="/shoelaces">Shoelaces</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If the user navigates to `/bubblegum/juicyfruit/nutrition` how can I replace the `{brand}` in the `Link`s with `juicyfruit`?  If this sidebar were in the `component` of a `Route` I know I could look at `this.props.match` but since the Sidebar stands alone, it doesn't have access to `match`.

Comment: Shouldn't you use template literals? Like this:      <Link to=\`/bubblegum/${brand}/nutrition\`>Nutritional Information</Link>

Comment: sure, but where does `brand` come from?  that's the real question.

Comment: Show all your code, we can't see here where does the brand come from.

Comment: This is hypothetical code from the tutorial I linked in the first line of my question. I forked it to show my scenario, which you can [see here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlx9l4wjzw).  Click on Bubblegum in the sidebar, then click on Juicyfruit in the main area.  You can see it switches to Juicyfuit in the header because `this.props.match` is available for the main section, but in the Sidebar, where can I get that parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this.props.match` to the Sidebar component from a parent component...

```
<Sidebar brand={this.props.match.params.brand}
  ...
```

or use `withRouter()` (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) to dynamically add the `match` prop to the component directly:

```
// import withRouter
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// in your render function of Sidebar component you now have access to `match`
const { match } = this.props;

// use it in your JSX
<li>
  <Link to={`/bubblegum/${match.params.brand}/history`}>History</Link>
</li>

// using `withRouter` requires wrapping your export
export withRouter(Sidebar)...
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm still missing something.  if you look at the code in [the fork I made](https://codesandbox.io/s/xlx9l4wjzw) I assume you're suggesting I add the `this.props.match.params.brand` to the Sidebar from the `SidebarExample` component.  However, if I add a `props` parameter to that functional component it's just an empty object.  I also updated that sandbox with a Sidebar component that is wrapped using `withRouter` and the `params` field is empty. I know an alternative would be to just use Redux to store what the user selected, but that seems overkill.

Comment: import { withRouter } from "react-router";

Comment: as opposed to `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"`?

Comment: it is not in `react-router-dom`, must import form the right package.

Comment: It definitely *is* in `react-router-dom` but maybe you mean there is a different version in `react-router`?  either way, I changed the code to use `withRouter` from `react-router` and it still behaves the same.  Please see the updated code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xlx9l4wjzw